# Pi Zero overlay to swap power and data usb ports?

Tags: usb-power, pi-zero

I have some right angle OTG cables that I can't use with the Pi Zero.  They collide into the power cable.

Is there any way to swap the purpose of the two ports so that the right angle cables for data hang off the edge of the PCB and the straight power cable goes into the socket closer to the center?  Perhaps some sort of overlay like swapping the purpose of the UARTs on the Pi 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

The micro USB ports are hard wired.

Comment: @goldilocks I don't know how these rumours get started.  It is not true.  The power microUSB socket does not have the USB data lines connected.

Comment: Yeah.  I think the source of the rumour is singular and his references do not support his claims.

Answer (score 2):

Backing [joan's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/57053/19949) with a reference: the official [schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/RPI-ZERO-V1_3_reduced.pdf) clearly show that the micro USB "power" port has no data lines connected.

[image]